# How to fetch a particular column from the list into another list of a particular employee in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a list 'EmployeeMaster' and another list 'LeaveDetails'. While entering the employeeID in 'leaveDetails' list, I need to display the employeeName and mailID in LeaveDetails list from EmployeeMaster list. I tried 'Lookup Column', but could not map the field to a particular employee. 
I have just started learning SharePoint. Kindly help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why a Lookup column won't work. In SharePoint 2010, in addition to the field that will appear on the edit form, you can select more fields to display by checking the boxes in the "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" section.